# In line following robot do this code work perfectly as iam unclear about the right and left moving programing lines

Tags: arduino-uno

```
    #define LS 2      // left sensor
#define RS 3      // right sensor

/*-------definning Outputs------*/
#define LM1 4       // left motor
#define LM2 5       // left motor
#define RM1 6       // right motor
#define RM2 7       // right motor

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LS, INPUT);
  pinMode(RS, INPUT);
  pinMode(LM1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LM2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RM1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RM2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if(digitalRead(LS) && digitalRead(RS))     // Move Forward
  {
    digitalWrite(LM1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LM2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RM1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RM2, LOW);
  }

  if(!(digitalRead(LS)) && digitalRead(RS))     // Turn right
  {
    digitalWrite(LM1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LM2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RM1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RM2, LOW);
  }

  if(digitalRead(LS) && !(digitalRead(RS)))     // turn left
  {
    digitalWrite(LM1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LM2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RM1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RM2, LOW);
  }

  if(!(digitalRead(LS)) && !(digitalRead(RS)))     // stop
  {
    digitalWrite(LM1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LM2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RM1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RM2, LOW);
  }
}
```

i got this code from a site.My doubt is if the left sensor is not reading means it has value of zero hence it is on black line and the right sensor is on white line.Then it should move to left side itself.BUt the program says it should moves to right.Iam a beginner.Please help me to clear my doubt

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the sensors are arranged. However, assuming they are setup like eyes on our heads, then the code would be correct.

If the left sensor does not see the line, but the right sensor does, then that means the line is on the right side of the robot, and thus turning to the right would bring the line back into view of the left sensor.